# Systemd: Logic behind configuration files in /usr/lib/

Tags: systemd, fhs

I was searching for the configuration for purging the `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` directories on a CentOS 7 default installation. After some searching, I came across the file `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf` which contains the actual retention periods.

I'm interested to learn the logic behind that file's placement. How could I have deduced that location without random googling, given that there is no unit called "tmpfiles"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I have deduced that location without random googling, given that there is no unit called "tmpfiles"?

```
% apropos tmp -l
systemd-gpt-auto-generator (8) - Generator for automatically discovering and mounting root, /home/, /srv/, /var/ and /var/tmp/ partitions, as well as discovering and enabling swap partitions, based on GPT partition type GUIDs.
systemd-tmpfiles (8) - Creates, deletes and cleans up volatile and temporary files and directories
systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service (8) - Creates, deletes and cleans up volatile and temporary files and directories
systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer (8) - Creates, deletes and cleans up volatile and temporary files and directories
systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service (8) - Creates, deletes and cleans up volatile and temporary files and directories
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service (8) - Creates, deletes and cleans up volatile and temporary files and directories
systemd-update-utmp (8) - Write audit and utmp updates at bootup, runlevel changes and shutdown
systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service (8) - Write audit and utmp updates at bootup, runlevel changes and shutdown
systemd-update-utmp.service (8) - Write audit and utmp updates at bootup, runlevel changes and shutdown
tmpfiles.d (5)       - Configuration for creation, deletion and cleaning of volatile and temporary files
utmpdump (1)         - dump UTMP and WTMP files in raw format
```

Ignoring the `utmp` entries, [`man 8 systemd-tmpfiles`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-tmpfiles.html) is the same as the other `systemd-tmpfiles-*` manpages, and it refers to [`man 5 tmpfiles.d`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html#), which has:

```
/etc/tmpfiles.d/*.conf
/run/tmpfiles.d/*.conf
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/*.conf


~/.config/user-tmpfiles.d/*.conf
$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/user-tmpfiles.d/*.conf
~/.local/share/user-tmpfiles.d/*.conf
…
/usr/share/user-tmpfiles.d/*.conf
```

The first set being for system configuration, and the second set for user configuration.

---

As to the logic, systemd configuration is generally in `/usr/lib` (or `/lib`, depending on the distro and `/usr` unification, but consistent within a distro), with corresponding override directories in `/etc` and `/run`, so there's nothing particularly surprising about that.

Comment: Is not this location (`/usr/lib`) of configuration files in some contradiction to FHS, which [states](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s06.html) that this folder must contain object files and libraries? Is not it a sort of historical relic?

Comment: The linked page also says "Applications may use a single subdirectory under /usr/lib. If an application uses a subdirectory, all architecture-dependent data exclusively used by the application must be placed within that subdirectory", and I guess in a sense the default systems configuration managed by the packaging system counts as architecture independent data (configuration that the admin is supposed to be able to modify go in `/etc/systemd`)